# ES6 Proxy not defined in React Native when not in remote debug mode?

Tags: react-native

I'm wrapping an imported SDK class with a Proxy so that I can eventually catch RequestExceptions, i.e. when there is no network connection to display error popups.

The app is working without issues in remote debugging mode, however, when I disable it the error `Can't find Variable: Proxy` is thrown. Do I need to import this explicitly somehow? Or is there an alternative method to wrap a class so that I can catch all of its exceptions?

Below is the code for the Proxy wrapper.

```
import Backend from 'backend-sdk';

import RequestException from 'backend-sdk/src/exceptions/RequestException';

let handler = {
  get: (target, name, receiver) => {
    try {
      return Reflect.get(target, name, receiver);
    } catch (e) {
      if (e instanceof RequestException) {
        console.error(e);
        //TODO Add a toast notification for failed API requests
      } else {
        throw e;
      }
    }
  }
};

export default new Proxy(new Backend(), handler);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Proxy is not pollyfilled in react native by default. It works in chrome debugger because react native uses chrome js engine during debugging see [Document on js environment](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html). You may try using [Proxy pollyfill](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/proxy-polyfill).

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. I also had to polyfill Reflect: https://github.com/tvcutsem/harmony-reflect

Comment: @Mastergalen could you please post some more comments about how you made it work with proxy-polifill + harmony-reflect.  I think Android still that issue and it's not really working for me.

Answer (score 2):

Note that [as of react-native 0.59](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2019/03/12/releasing-react-native-059#-updated-jsc-means-performance-gains-and-64-bit-support-on-android), react-native on Android now uses a more modern version of JavaScriptCore that includes Proxy support.

Comment: Thank you for this! Does the same apply to iOS? I'm using react-native 0.63 - i can't find specifcially where 0.59 says they support iOS

Comment: I believe that react-native iOS uses the native JavaScriptCore bundled with iOS, and that has supported Proxy for a long time now. (https://caniuse.com/proxy)